# Why animate.css only works on DIV elements

Tags: html, css

I use the `animate.css` library for a long time and it works great but today I found out that it does not work with `SPAN` or any other element which is not a `DIV`. Does anyone know the reason and how do I fix it?

Check the really simple example below (code is below):

https://jsfiddle.net/214gdyrw/

When you open the link above you can see that `AAA` and `CCC` animate automatically (on page load), however `bbb` does not. The only difference is that one is `div` and other is `span`. How can I make the `span` also animate?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<!-- Animate.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.0/animate.min.css" />

</head>

<body>

    <div class="animated bounce">AAA</div>

    <span class="animated bounce">bbb</span>

    <div class="animated bounce">CCC</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's the display option, use `display:block` or `display:inline-block` on the `span`/`a` tags - https://jsfiddle.net/andyjh07/1estv24a/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block` on the `span`.

This will fix you issue.

Element needs to have block behaviour, not inline.

Comment: `inline-block` is inline level, not block level.

Comment: I dont find anywhere on documentation about that, amazing.

Comment: @Alohci inline-block worked, I have no idea why.

Comment: @Samul - Sure, the solution is fine - it's the explanation that's flawed.

Comment: @Alohci EFA....